# 5Ghz wifi suddenly stopped working and isn't connecting

Tags: 18.04, wireless

My laptop was working perfectly fine with my 5Ghz AP `XYZ_5G` but suddenly it stopped connecting to that AP. Note that other devices are working perfectly fine with `XYZ_5G`.
Laptop is currently connected with `XYZ` AP (2.4Ghz). and I can still see `XYZ_5G` in AP list.

1. `XYZ_5G` channel is 149 @ 80Mhz and router didn't switch that channel. (iwlist channels isn't showing 149)
2. There is no restriction in place from my router against mac address of my laptop (I am admin).

Full wireless-info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BCH5RB2mym/  (Created using https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info)

```
##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-1099-oem #109-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 14:11:31 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, mem_sleep_default=deep, usbcore.quirks=2386:3119:k, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm Atheros
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ath10k_pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-1099-oem
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
...
##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Karachi (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.745 GHz

wlp2s0    Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-31 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"XYZ"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000017bf6a85b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 5476ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'AP2' [AC2]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=27/70  Signal level=-83 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AP2"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004ec69d6f4b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6880ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'AP3' [AC3]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AP3"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              11 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000049cc5aface
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6156ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'AP4' [AC4]>
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=19/70  Signal level=-91 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AP4"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000083492e17e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6236ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'AP5' [AC5]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"AP5"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000051c0634be0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 5768ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
                    Channel:149
                    Frequency:5.745 GHz
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"XYZ_5G"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000017c46149d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1136ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### dmesg #############################

[  117.298284] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  117.299714] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  132.177320] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  132.208373] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  132.209849] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  132.211127] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  132.212368] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  143.008477] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  147.093846] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  147.125086] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  147.126428] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  147.127750] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  147.129000] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  161.985223] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  162.016043] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  162.017383] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  162.018780] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  162.020144] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  172.008993] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  229.790920] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]>
[  229.836363] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  229.838518] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  229.841624] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  229.845030] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  229.847864] wlp2s0: associated
[  229.935923] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[  253.275519] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  253.320555] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  253.351926] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  254.781635] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  255.338805] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  255.339976] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  260.310559] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  260.341342] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  260.342980] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  260.344510] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  260.345893] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  265.711475] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  265.742865] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  265.744264] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  265.745827] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  265.747139] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  271.616293] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[  271.647357] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[  271.649619] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[  271.651038] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[  271.652408] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[  279.008406] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[  281.552270] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]>
[  281.598367] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  281.600132] wlp2s0: authenticated
[  281.601668] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[  281.605315] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  281.608139] wlp2s0: associated
[  281.618416] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 1025.763634] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[ 1026.150392] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[ 1026.182133] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[ 1026.183643] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[ 1026.185104] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[ 1026.186617] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[ 1031.256747] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[ 1031.287290] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[ 1031.288737] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[ 1031.290210] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[ 1031.291547] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[ 1036.648906] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[ 1036.679379] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[ 1036.681077] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[ 1036.682569] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[ 1036.684122] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[ 1042.537265] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]>
[ 1042.567772] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 1/3)
[ 1042.569136] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 2/3)
[ 1042.570573] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> (try 3/3)
[ 1042.571816] wlp2s0: authentication with <MAC 'XYZ_5G' [AC6]> timed out
[ 1051.195209] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[ 1052.495304] wlp2s0: authenticate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]>
[ 1052.543362] wlp2s0: send auth to <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1052.545076] wlp2s0: authenticated
[ 1052.552213] wlp2s0: associate with <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 1052.555583] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'XYZ' [AC1]> (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1052.558066] wlp2s0: associated
[ 1052.566497] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

**Update # 1**

I know switching the channel would definitely resolve this issue but I am curious to know the root cause of this issue.
Below screenshot is from my another laptop running Ubuntu 19.10. it is also not showing channel 149 using `iwlist channel` but you can see that it is still connected to that AP `Current Frequency:5.745 GHz`

[image: Another laptop working fine with that same AP1]

**Update # 2**

My country (Pakistan, PK) only allows 149, 153, 157, 161 & 165 5GHz Channels (Reference: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeNetworking/comments/dk382q/android_devices_can_only_detect_channel_149_153/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

I tried following channels:

1. 36 (not showing in mobiles but working on laptop)
2. 60 (not showing in both laptop and mobiles)
3. 140 (not showing in both laptop and mobiles)

So my best bet is to make it work with channel 149 that was working before or select some other non DFS/TPC channel that would work with all my devices. I don't want to break any law by changing country.

**Update # 3**

Same AP with channel 149 is now working fine on that laptop although I changed nothing on AP and that laptop.

Full network info: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FBVrnryx6v/

Note that `iw reg get` result is now different. Why is that?
Now it is `country US: DFS-FCC`. Previously it was `country 00: DFS-UNSET`

```
##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Karachi (based on set time zone)

global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 144 : 5.72 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Current Frequency=5.745 GHz (Channel 149)
```

Comment: Try setting the router to use channel 140 and see if the problem is solved. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema just updated my quest ion and have added screenshot of `iwlist channel` using my another laptop on which that AP is working. I will definitely switch channels but I am curious to know the root cause (why it suddenly stopped working even though my router didn't change channel).

Comment: Report back after changing channels.

Comment: @heynnema done. check my update # 2

Comment: If you're sure that you've got the correct wireless password, try rebooting the router by unplugging it from AC power, count to 15, replug, and retest channel 149.

Comment: @heynnema Check update # 3. Password was correct. I changed nothing and it is now working again.

Comment: @heynnema I restarted router yesterday after I faced this issue but issue wasn't resolved even after that.

Comment: The iwlist command shows two channels, 144 and 149, that were not there before. Something changed on the computer.

Comment: @heynnema I didn't change anything. Apparently different country channel whitelist was loaded that blacklisted channel 149 when I faced this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I studied and found that this problem is related to regulatory domain change although I am not sure how that happened.

There is a [Wireless regulatory database (used by CRDA)](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb.git/tree/db.txt?id=HEAD) that has country specific rules.

it was `country US: DFS-FCC` which was working fine with channel 149 @ 80Mhz.

Somehow it changed to `country 00: DFS-UNSET` in the middle of the day when I faced this issue. Next day it was again set to `country US: DFS-FCC` and WiFi starts working again.

More info about wireless regulatory infrastucture: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory